# Visual Source Safe - Comparison tool

Tags: plugins, comparison, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Can i replace the default comparison tools in Visual Source Safe with some other tool to compare/merge (like WinMerge - an open source tool) ?

I am using VSS 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSS options, there is a tab called "Custome Editors" you can set your external application to be used on different actions. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181146%28VS.80%29.aspx)